# Is this a one to many or many to many relationship?

Tags: database, database-design, entity, entity-relationship

So I'm making an E/R diagram based on drugs. It states that each drug is produced by a given pharmaceutical company and the trade name of the drug is identified among the products of the given pharmaceutical company. So here's the E/R diagram I drew up:
[image: E/R diagram]
Now the biggest question I have about this is, are these relationships supposed to be one to many or many to many? Each one relationship is represented by an arrow (where the pointed arrow means at most one and the rounded arrow means exactly one). I first assumed that a single drug identified by a single trade name would come from just one pharmaceutical company but would it be possible for a single drug to come from multiple pharmaceutical company's? I'm also not sure if it's supposed to be a 3 way relationship or not.

Comment: What reference are you using to draw your diagrams? How does it explain them?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is really a technical question you can find the answer to here.  It would probably be wise to further clarify with your client, but from pure wording I would assume.

1.) 1 Drug - 1 Trade Name - 1 Company
2.) 1 Company has Many Drugs

From general knowledge of US drugs, different companies have their unique versions of drugs with the same active ingredient, but these are all filed under different trade names, maintaining 1 trade name - 1 company relationship.

For example, ibuprofen (generic) is sold under both Advil and Motrin (separate trade names).

Answer (score 0):

In this style of ER diagram, Chen's original, the diamond denotes a ternary 
"relationship" type, aka association type, among/on the three participant "entity" types symbolized by the boxes. As in an application relationship/association, as in "Entity-Relationship Model". The lines showing participations correspond to FKs (foreign keys).

In such a diagram each line gets labeled by the number or range giving the number of entities in each entity set which is allowed in a relationship set. The table for the relationship would have a FK for each line. Per Chen it would be described as (in order company-name-drug) (at-most-1)-to-(exactly-1)-to-N relationship (assuming the unlabeled line means any number). There is a style with a cardinality at each end of a line.

Misunderstandings/misrepresentations/misappropriations of Chen style by older & newer methods & products (although quite mainstream) lead to different so-called ER diagrams.

One such style only shows entity type boxes with relationships shown by connecting lines labeled by relationship names. The 1:many relationships can be implemented by a FK attribute in one of the entity type tables, although they needn't be, and although that's contrary to Chen ER modeling, which would use a table. Typically, for n-ary relationships for n>2, instead of just having three line segments connect at a point the point is replaced by a box for what in Chen is an "associative entity" type. The lines would then be participations/FKs under Chen. *All* lines now represent 1:many relationships. Other so-called ER diagrams just have boxes for tables and lines for FKs and don't even have relationships on entities in the Chen sense. The use of  lines that only ever denote 1:many relationships and/or FKs lead to lines and FKs being (wrongly but ubiquitously) called "relationships". (Which seems to be how you understand the word.)

The wikipedia entry on [E-R modeling (and E-R diagrams)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) is currently reasonable.